# Chart.js V4.3.0 X-Axis Labels Not Aligning

Tags: chart.js

Using Chart.js v4.3.0, I'm trying to left-align x-axis labels on a vertical bar chart. They are centered by default and my reading of [the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.0/axes/cartesian/linear.html) indicates that adding this to the chart's `options` would do it:

```
ticks: {
  align: 'start',
},
```

Weirdly, that moves the labels slightly right and still not aligned.

CodePen demo of issue: https://codepen.io/ChrisBup/pen/qBQWqPw

#### Expected Behavior:

[image: Screenshot 2023-06-04 at 10 42 25 PM]

I set `labelOffset` to get the screenshot, but as it only takes a number of pixels, it's not a responsive solution.

#### Extra Context:

Chart.js version: 4.3.0

Browser: Chrome Version 113.0.5672.126 (Official Build) (arm64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the align option is working as designed. The position where the option is applied is related to the middle of the "tick". It's implemented as textAlign property of Context2D https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textAlign

You can change the position of the ticks by a custom plugin:

```js
const p = {
  id: 'my',
  beforeDraw(chart) {
    const scale = chart.scales.x;
    const items = scale.getLabelItems();
    const {data} = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
    for (let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
      const {x, width} = data[i];
      const newX = x - width / 2;
      items[i].options.translation.splice(0, 1, newX);
    }
  },  
}
```

You should add the plugin

```js
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [p],
  data: {
  ...
```

and then set `align` option to the X scale ticks to `'start'`.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/qBQWxZQ